# Different html source code when I use CURL to scrape page from Marketwatch.com in compare to using CHROME

Tags: selenium-webdriver, curl, dynamic, webdriver

when I use CURL (Window Command Prompt) to scrape HTML source from https://www.marketwatch.com/tools/screener/market?exchange=nasdaq&subreport=largestpercentgainreport, it return HTML source that is different then the source that I use View Page Source in CHROME. I am not sure if MarketWatch uses dynamic page or what. CURL was working perfectly with MarketWatch.com until a week ago.

I tried using agent header, Python Selenium with CHROME web-driver, etc. and still get the 'not up-to-date' HTML source code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Error must be in your code you will need to mimic the browser headers, cookies etc to get same results or the site will detect the request not to be valid and block it

I've written the code to scrape data from the [site](https://www.marketwatch.com/tools/screener/market?exchange=nasdaq&subreport=largestpercentgainreport) you provided

```py
import requests

session = requests.session()

url = "https://www.marketwatch.com:443/tools/screener/market?exchange=nasdaq&subreport=largestpercentgainreport"

header = {"Sec-Ch-Ua": "\"Chromium\";v=\"121\", \"Not A(Brand\";v=\"99\"", 
        "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0", "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": "\"Linux\"", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.6167.160 Safari/537.36", 
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7", 
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none", "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate", "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1", 
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
        "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8", "Priority": "u=0, i"}

resp = session.get(url, headers=header)
print(resp.text)
```

Rendering the `resp.text` results in the same page as  https://www.marketwatch.com/tools/screener/market?exchange=nasdaq&subreport=largestpercentgainreport so i believe it works fine

Comment: Thanks for your effort. However, it is not working as I want. You can compare the content within resp.text with the content displayed in CHROME and they are different. I think the site has done something to avoid people scraping their site by providing not up-to-dated HTML source

Comment: @ K.K. wdym?? i am literally able to scrape the latest data from the site with the help of above code . The site you provided keeps changing it's html every second so in order to get the same source you will need to fire up the url in chrome and the script at the same time and you will get the same page as chrome. For checking the above save it to a file `scrape.py` and do `python3 scrape.py >> index.html` then drag and drop the file to any browser ...

Comment: Thanks ZwachReck. I tried your code just now during the US stock market opening hours and your coding generates index.html that always contains the same contents. Where as using CHROME to visit the URL, it will give you the most updated contents every time you visit. Maybe when you testing your code, the US stock market was closed. Please try your code during 9:30am EST to 4pm EST and you know what I am saying.  But thanks anyway!